# At the Helmholtz decomposition proof: why is the additional term vanishing?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

It can be found: $$F_l(r) = -\dfrac{1}{4\,\pi}\nabla\int_V \dfrac{\nabla'\cdot F(r')}{|r-r'|}\,\mathrm{d^3}r' + \dfrac{1}{4\,\pi}\nabla\int_{S}\dfrac{F(r')}{|r-r'|}\cdot \mathrm{\hat{n}\,d^2}r'$$

which is the longitudinal component of the Helmholtz decomposition

Now why the second term reduces to $\mathbf{0}$ if $F(r)$ is regular at infinity as well as the surface sprawls to infinity.

I can only image the numerator will remain constant but the denominator will go down to $\mathbf{0}$

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by the "longitudinal component"?

Comment: This is yet a question to answer why it is called like this but it is common convention to just give this name to $F_l(r)$

Comment: By "regular at infinity" I assume it means $\boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol x)\to 0$ as $|\boldsymbol x|\to\infty$ so taking $V\to\Bbb R^n$ I think is what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, I guess this is just the reason why the integral vanishes.